# Finding Curvature

Tags: differential-geometry, curvature

I have came across $2$ formulas to find curvature:

1. $$k(s)=\|\alpha''(s)\|$$
2. $$k(t)=\frac{\det(\alpha'(t),\alpha''(t))}{\|\alpha'(t)\|^3}$$

What are the difference between the two formulas?

Comment: one formula is expresses in terms of a parameter $t.$ The other is expressed in terms of the arc length of the curve ($s =  \|a'(t)\|$)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first one applies to the case where $\Vert\alpha'(s)\Vert=1$.

The second one applies generally.

Let's use the first one, $\alpha''(s)$, as the definition of the curvature.

If $\Vert\alpha'(s)\Vert=1$, look at $\alpha(s(t))$ for some $s(t)$. Then
$$
\frac{d}{dt}\alpha(s(t)) = s'(t)\cdot\alpha'(s(t))
$$
and
$$
\left(\frac{d}{dt}\right)^2\alpha(s(t))
= s''(t)\cdot\alpha'(s(t)) + s'(t)^2\cdot\alpha''(s(t)).
$$
In the plane,
$$
\det\left(\frac{d}{dt}\alpha(s(t)),\left(\frac{d}{dt}\right)^2\alpha(s(t))\right)
= |s'(t)|^3\cdot\Vert\alpha''(s(t))\Vert,
$$
while in 3-dimensional space you'd express the same using the cross-product,
$$
\left\Vert\frac{d}{dt}\alpha(s(t))\times\left(\frac{d}{dt}\right)^2\alpha(s(t))\right\Vert
= |s'(t)|^3\cdot\Vert\alpha''(s(t))\Vert,
$$
and then divide this by $|s'(t)|^3$ where $|s'(t)|=\Vert d\alpha(s(t))/dt\Vert$.

Comment: So using the second one, I can't get to wrong?

Comment: Right. The second one applies generally, not only when $\Vert\alpha'(s)\Vert=1$.